# ASP mvc how to block multiple clicking button in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Is there easy way to block button after 1 click ?

I tried some method from google (javascript) but its not working

There is some sample of my code :

```
.
.
.
        <tr>
            <td>
                choose files 
            </td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("addItem", "Items", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "uploadForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                { 
                    @(Html.Telerik().Upload().Name("Attachments"))
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Stringgg
            </td>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => zlec.Tresc, new { required = "required", style = "width:100%" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        </TABLE>

        <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
```

In controller im adding some rows to table in db ( [HttpPOST] )

After fast double click in "Add Item", its adding 2 rows

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript or Jquery is your best option to disable the button onclick (there are plenty of examples online). Putting code in your post action to stop duplicates may be appropriate for your solution.  You could use the sessionId maybe?

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple javascript to disable after it is clicked

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
<button type="submit" id="btn">Add Item</button>
```